# How to append lines in open file before empty line to a dictionary, and then continue appending the following lines until the next empty line?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, readline

Coding beginner, thanks in advance!

I have a text file like:

```
A
B
1
2

C
D
1
2
3
4

E
F
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

What I'm trying to do is generate a dictionary that turns each section before the empty line into a key and value pair. For example, my dictionary for the text file should be:

```
{('A','B'): [[1],[2]], ('C','D'):[[1, 3], [2, 4]], ('E','F'):[[1, 3, 5],[2, 4, 6]]}
```

Right now, I started off my function like this:

```
while line != '':
    # rest of function to append to dictionary here
```

But I've realized that this only works until the first empty line. If I try to continue reading and print the lines after the function, because of the nature of the while loop, the first line printed is D instead of C. How can I fix this WITHOUT importing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you can do it (assuming the file structure is exactly as you said):

First create a string containing all lines:

```
lines = ''.join(list(open("test.txt")))
#'A\nB\n1\n2\n\nC\nD\n1\n2\n3\n4\n\nE\nF\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6'
```

Then split into pairs:

```
pairs = lines.split('\n\n')
#['A\nB\n1\n2', 'C\nD\n1\n2\n3\n4', 'E\nF\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6']
```

Finally within each pair split key and value:

```
pairs = lines.split('\n\n')
result = {}
for pair in pairs:
    data = pair.split('\n')
    key = (data[0], data[1])
    first_value = data[2::2]
    second_value = data[3::2]
    result[key] = [first_value, second_value]
result
```

Output:

```
{('A', 'B'): [['1'], ['2']],
 ('C', 'D'): [['1', '3'], ['2', '4']],
 ('E', 'F'): [['1', '3', '5'], ['2', '4', '6']]}
```

Note: `data[2::2]` means array slicing start from position `2` and iterate every 2 elements

Comment: So sorry, I didn't know I should put the exact file structure (first time on this site) so the file structure isn't as simple as this. I updated my main question with the file structure! Thank you for answering so quickly!

Comment: Long wait on my part because I realized I made another mistake but I managed to adapt your solution to mine! Very helpful, I'm grateful you used such clear language because I understood everything that was going on. Thank you so much again!!

Answer (score 0):

**Do this:**

```py
txt = x.read_text() # read file as string here
txt = txt.split('\n\n')
txt = list(map(lambda y: y.split('\n'), txt))

keys = list(map(lambda y: y[:2], txt))
values = list(map(lambda y: y[2:], txt))
d = {tuple(key): [[value[0::2]], [value[1::2]]] for key in keys for value in values}
```

Comment: This approach is clean! but will consume slightly more time!

Comment: Thank you! Went with the other approach because I was halfway done when I saw this but it's great to see a shorter method. Tried upvoting but can't since I don't have enough reputation, I'll come back to try again when I do!

Comment: It's ok!! you don't have to :)